# Argument of type import().Client is not assignable to parameter of type import().Client

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two modules:

In one module I reference a function from another module `run`:

**@myorg/server**

```
import { Client } from '.'
import { Middleware } from '@myorg/middleware'

let client = new Client()
Middleware.run(client)
```

Then in the other module I reference only a type like this:

**@myorg/middleware**

```
// References a '.d.ts' file
import { Client } from '@myorg/server'

export class Middleware {

  public run(client: Client){
    // Do some stuff
  }

}
```

When I have this setup, `Middleware.run(client)` gives me the following error:

> Argument of type 'import("/framework/server/src/Client").Client' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/framework/server/types/Client").Client'.

As the error points out `src` (the actual code) and `types` (the `.d.ts` file) are not compatible. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I guess that's because you are importing a type meanwhile for compiler it's like if you were importing a module. Therefore, you should consider other ways of including types. You could use `types` in `tsconfig.json` to declare your types.

Comment: If I use them there do I still need the `import {abc} from 'module-name'`?

Comment: Usually you don't. If you don't succeed you may also try this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html. However, the option with declaring in `tsconfig.json` should work for you as well as enabling you to declare some folder which contains all third party type files.

Comment: If I remove the import for `import { Client } from '@myorg/server'` and add it to the `tsconfig.json => "types": ["@myorg/server"]` I get the error **Cannot find name 'Client'.** I also would like to not use triple slash directives

Comment: If `server` is a `server.d.ts` file try to use `@myorg` instead. Also, don't forget to restart your TypeScript watch if it's running. In `types` a folder is usually declared

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should also import the type `Client` in `@myorg/middleware` from the same source file that `@myorg/server` imports it from.

Explanation: In `@myorg/middleware` you are importing the type `Client` from a type declaration file (.d.ts) which I assume you have referenced it on top of the file with a `///` directive. Whereas in the `@myorg/server` that `Client` type is directly imported from the actual source code. Therefore Typescript does not consider those two as the same and that's why you get this error.

Comment: If I import with the same type `@myorg/server` just imports itself: `@myorg/server`

Comment: Hmmm.... Looks like this is working... I didn't think referencing the module to itself would work...

Comment: I could help you further if you give me the real code you are using.

Comment: [Middleware](https://github.com/red5-server/framework/blob/master/middleware/src/Middleware.ts#L13) and [Server](https://github.com/red5-server/framework/blob/master/server/src/Server.ts#L176) I do believe your suggestions are working now though...

Comment: I took a look at the code and yes, that's the right solution. You are importing the exact same type in both modules and therefore it works as it should

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem, except in my case, the imports were the exact same, **except for differing in file name casing.**

**file1.ts**

```
import { Hub } from './hubs';
```

**file2.ts**

```
import { Hub } from './Hubs';
```

Notice the `./Hubs` vs `./hubs` casing.  They were different which resulted in the error:

```
ERROR in app/file1.ts:107:45 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'import("MY_PATH/app/Hubs").Hub' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("MY_PATH/app/hubs").Hub'.
```